# Laravel 4 redirect post url and data after auth

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Hi i'm new to laravel want to redirect a post request and data after user authenticate to website. I'm using Redirect::intended('/') but this is making only get request not post.

After searching on google i found this as a nearest solution [Auth filter redirecting back to original POST request in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900193/auth-filter-redirecting-back-to-original-post-request-in-laravel/20712245#20712245)

But in this the page is loading with no post data. When i checked in network in google chrome it is showing as GET request. but in route i defined that as post request.

Route.php -- routes

```
Route::post('/up', 'HomeController@up');
```

up.blade.php  posting data "html:{"data":"data"}"

```
<?php if(isset($_POST["html"])) 
    echo "'" . utf8_encode($_POST["html"]) . "'";
?>
```

In Google chrome network

```
Remote Address:[::1]:8000
Request URL:http://localhost:8000/up
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
```

Previously(extending classes) i was getting method not found error

Comment: Try a 307 redirect to force the browser to use the same request method.

Comment: We need to see the view

Comment: Added view code above